# How to download pages that redirect after login?

Tags: perl, bash

Normally pages that have a login form can be downloaded with

```
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies cookies --keep-session-cookies \
     --post-data="username=example&password=example" \
     "https://example.com/index.php?title=Special:Userlogin&returntotitle="

wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies=cookies \
     --no-parent -r --level=2 -nc -E \
     https://example.com/Special:Sitemap
```

But in the case of DekiWiki sites, this doesn't work, if login is required.

The problem seams to be described in `man wget`

> Note: if Wget is redirected after the POST request is completed, it will not send the
>   POST data to the redirected URL.  This is because URLs that process POST often respond
>   with a redirection to a regular page, which does not desire or accept POST.  It is not
>   completely clear that this behavior is optimal; if it doesn't work out, it might be
>   changed in the future.

**Question**

Can this be done using Perl e.g. with perhaps `HTML::TreeBuilder 3` or `HTML::TokeParser` or `Mechanize` or any other Perl module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some sites that require a login do not send the cookie back with the response.

Instead they send a redirection response (302 Object Moved), which most browsers follow automatically and then the cookie is sent in the response for that redirect page.

I use curl to do this by enabling the curl_opt FOLLOW_LOCATION, for the command line tool one uses the -location option. It is a free tool like wget.

```
curl --cookie cookie.txt --cookie-jar cookie.txt \
     --data-urlencode "username=example&password=example" \
     --insecure --location https://example.com/index.php?title=Special:Userlogin&returntotitle= -o downloadedfile.html https://example.com/Special:Sitemap
```

http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Also, sometimes a login form expects a multi-part/form-data post instead of just a application/x-www-form-urlencoded post. To make curl do a multi-part/form-data post change to he --data-urlencode to -F.

Comment: Very interesting. Is it also possible to mirror the site? In my example I use wget's `--no-parent -r --level=2`.

Comment: Do you mean recursively download all pages pointed to from the original page? No, curl has nor -r --level=2 equivalent, however, libcurl, an API interface, could easily be programmed to parse an html page, and download all the links in that page. Libcurl has bindings for the following languages (and more): 
C, C++, Java, Lisp, .NET, Object-Pascal, Pascal, Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, Visual Basic

Comment: @Motes, "-cookie-jar" needs to be changed to "--cookie-jar", right?